# Linux Mint Ra-Link Wi-Fi driver issues

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, linux-mint

So, the default drivers on the USB stick I used to install Mint seemed to work ok, but after I got booted into the installed OS and started updating stuff, it seems to have broken. My google-fu showed a lot of users from kernel 3.1 ish era having much the same issue, but all the fixes seem to be too old to be relevant to my machine. I DID try to use an install script for rt3290sta drivers, but it errors out

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/tmp/build/rt3290sta-2.6.0.0/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/build/rt3290sta-2.6.0.0/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Error 1
Makefile:1403: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/build/rt3290sta-2.6.0.0/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/build/rt3290sta-2.6.0.0/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic'
Makefile:380: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

uname -ra

```
4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci -nn

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
```

Edit: Woops, wrong line from lspci, now it's the Wireless adapter

Comment: Assuming you are using the old driver source from Ralink/MediaTek for kernel 2.6 to about 3.2, it won't work, the 4.4 kernel uses different headers and formats. TBH, 99% of people who attempt to get this working on newer Linux installations fail, Ralink cards, especially this one, are known to be... umm... less than well supported in Linux. You are better off to just trash it and get something better supported that was also an option on your laptop, of if this is a USB WiFi adapter get a new one. Search RT3290 here and you will see your not the first to have problems with Linux and all fail.

Comment: Well, that's good to know, but also frustrating. I actually do have an external card I got specifically because Kali has native drivers for it AND it can do packet injection for wi-fi pen testing; I imagine that should work just fine in Mint as well.

Comment: Sorry for the bad news... but your other adapter will likely work just fine.